# Dynamically get image paths in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jakarta-ee, javax.imageio

this is my code below

```
public BufferedImage icon32 = loadBufferedImage("/icon/icon32.png");
public BufferedImage icon64 = loadBufferedImage("/icon/icon64.png");
private BufferedImage loadBufferedImage(String string)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(string));
        return bi;
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

}

I just wanted to know if there's a way to dynamically get the images from my image directory in eclipse instead of having to access them one by one

Comment: If your images are always *files* in the file system, you can use `new File("icon").listFiles();` to obtain the images (but still load them one by one). However, if they are *resources* in your program, ie. in a JAR or on classpath, you can't, and need to explicitly access them like you do.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for replying! I get what you're saying but if they're files in the file system and I load them one by one using new File("icon").listFiles(); how do I display them in my jsp using the src attribute or is there any other way to display them in my jsp, that's what i've been trying to figure out. I basically want to display my images in my jsp dynamically either through resources or from my my file system.